# Java DatagramSocket on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, udp, windows-xp-sp3

Guys im having some trouble with some inconsistency of running a piece of code on Windows XP and Windows 7.

Basically im trying to send a UDP packet by doing,

```
DatagramSocket sendSocket = new DatagramSocket();
DatagramPacket dummyPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[ 1 ], 1,
            configuration.remoteAddress, DUMMY_PORT);
try {
    sendSocket.send(dummyPacket);
    log("send dummy packet succeeded so assume already connected");
} catch (NoRouteToHostException nrthe) {
    log("alreadyConnected: no route to host so assume not connected");
} catch (Exception e) {
    errorHandler.handleException("send dummy packet failed", e, ErrorAndWarningHandler.ERROR);
}
```

On Windows 7 I'm always getting success whether I connect to the remote host or not. Where as on Windows XP I'm getting an exception which is what I am expecting. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here for it to not work on Windows 7 ????

Appreciate it

Comment: I think it's the XP behavior that's odd - you don't need to be connected to send a UDP datagram.

Comment: windows xp throws an exception when this happens however windows 7 doesnt .... this is basically my question. if it does throw an error then it allows me to establish a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be some sort of discrepancy on Windows 7 and Windows XP. As sje397 it could be the behavior on XP that is wrong. I confirmed the behavior by writing a small VB application to write to the UDP socket. XP doesnt allow it but Windows 7 does. Ohh well guess I will have to find an alternative solution like may be pinging an ip or something to check the connection is alive.